# How to generate mongdb objectid in django to insert a nested object with id

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, objectid

I am using mongoengine in django.I want to create a objectid which I can insert in nested object wholesalers of firm collection

```
class wholesaler(EmbeddedDocument):
    wid                 =   ObjectIdField()
    name                =   StringField(required = True,min_length = 3)

class firm(Document):
    name                = StringField(required=True)
    wholesalers         = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(wholesaler))
```

In View.py

```
wholesaler1 = wholesaler(wid = ??
                         ,name = '')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import bson
bson.objectid.ObjectId()
=> ObjectId('55dada4065d1ac2052207776')
```